# Унифицировать название сайта при добавлении способа входа

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, способы-входа

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add

1. FB: **Stack Overflow на русском**.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. VK: **Stack Exchange**.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Yandex: **Stack Overflow in Russian**.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо бы вообще все варианты к первому свести, но, кажется VK и Яндекс это чисто ru расширения, на других сайтах помимо FB и Google других не видел. Недавно тоже эту часть затрагивал на MSE: [раз](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328327/339911) и [два](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328336/339911).